# Cannot Post users/login ExpressJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, express

I am trying to create login page using express, NodeJs, Angular, mysql. Problem is while clicking on login button "Cannot POST users/login" error thrown. Please help.

I have created server.js and db.js files then route/Users.js and models/Users.js

**Authentication.service.ts**

```
    public login(user:TokenPayload): Observable<any>{
    const base = this.http.post('/users/login', user)

    const request = base.pipe(
        map((data: TokenResponse) =>{
            if(data.token){
                this.saveToken(data.token)
            }
            return data
        })
    )
    return request
}
```

In `Authentication.service.ts` file, i think problem is with ('/users/login') but i am not sure.

DB connection is successful but don't know why its throwing `Cannot POST users/login`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Error you provided look like server is not exposing  "users/login". Can you try it from postman and  also without this login security

Comment: Hi Ritesh, I have tried with postman also.Without security Its showing "Could not get any response"  and with security "Cannot LINK /users/login".